# How do I calculate the percentage of a value in a column based on constraints on it , in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I was wondering how to calculate the percentage of a certain value based on constraints on it

For instance, let's say I have a hypothetical table called Cats. I insert the following values into it:

```
Create table Cats (Cat_ID int, Cat_name varchar(max), Cat_Hometown varchar(max), Gender varchar(max), Birth_Year int);

INSERT INTO Cats (Cat_ID, Cat_Name, Cat_Hometown, Gender, Birth_year)
VALUES (1, 'Blue','Boston','M', 1980),
(2, 'Steamer','Plymouth','F', 1999),
(3, 'Stack','Newton','F', 1980),
(4, 'Overflow','Boston','M', 1978),
(5, 'CatorDog','Allston','F', 1999);
```

What if I want to determine the percentage of the female cats that were born in the leading hometown of the year 1980? I can't seem to figure it out.
By **leading** hometown I mean the most common hometown.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  It is actually unclear what you intend by the numerator and denominator (actually, the numerator is pretty clear).

Comment: Are you capable of solving any part of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming leading hometown means the most number of rows in the table for a given year, you can `order by` the count and get the most common one. Then use conditional aggregation to get the percentage. `AVG(gender='F')` uses the fact that MySQL treats conditions as booleans returning 1 for True and 0 for False.

```
select AVG(gender='F') 
from cats
where birth_year=1980  and 
cat_hometown in (select cat_hometown 
                 from cats
                 where birth_year=1980 
                 group by cat_hometown
                 order by count(*) desc 
                 limit 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out the most common home town.  That is a bit challenging, but a subquery helps.  So:

```
select avg(c.Gender = 'Female' and c.Birth_Year = 1980 and c.Cat_Hometown = ch.Cat_Hometown)
from cats c cross join
     (select c2.Cat_Hometown
      from cats c2
      group by c2.Cat_Hometown
      order by count(*) desc
      limit 1
     ) ch;
```